# Get json store data from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was storing Json data in Php database like this ["4","2"]. Problem is that i want to get data from json id using where clause . Is there any solution for that?

I was also use this JSON_CONTAINS but not working.

SELECT `membermaster`.* FROM `membermaster` WHERE `membermaster`.`status` = 'Active' AND `membermaster`.`role` = 'client' AND JSON_CONTAINS(client_type,"2")

Sorry for my bad english. Thank You.

Comment: Which kind of PHP Database do you use? Where you want to get the data? Which language are you using? Which code did your try yet? Where is the exact problem?

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin  and i want to search (where clause) on json array value filed like this ["4","2"].

Comment: table be like this
id  type
1   ["1","2"]
2   ["2"] 
3   ["2","3"]

SELECT * FROM membermaster WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(client_type, "$[0]")="2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you tell which Mysql version you are using because **JSON_CONTAINS** only will work in greater than equal MySql 5.7 version? It also depends on the server setting and database open extension settings.

If you want to get data using the where clause you can write a query like below.

```
SELECT membermaster FROM membermaster WHERE membermaster.status = 'Active' AND membermaster.role = 'client' AND client_type like '%"2"%';
```

Or if you want you can use regex also.

Comment: Thanks, you are save my lots of time

Comment: You are welcome @MaulikNai
If this answer did help you upvote this so it will help other developers also